# How can I make the data in percentile?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this sample total users of 20. If I'll  `console.log((acc[month] / totalUsers) * 100);`, it shows the correct percentage which is 15. However, I'm having a hard time passing it on the chart since it'll show an incorrect number. Currently for the doses1 it has the value of 3. So what I wanted to do was something like this: (3/20)*100 so I could get the value of 15. And then pass that 15 in the correct `doses1` array.

How can I fix this? Thank you.

This is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/filter-and-reduce-data-per-month-8bvv9?file=/src/App.js:1713-1759

Comment: Use a new state variable, set it after calculating the number, use it in your chart data and your chart should update accordingly.

Comment: Hello there! could you please read the guidelines on how to properly ask a question because it will help the members of the community understand your issue better and enables you to find a solution and also help someone that encounters a similar problem in the future.
Now I don't understand what is the issue here what do you want to achieve? do you want to display the percentage on the Line chart? you have 2 arrays that you're using to display the data `doses1` and `doses2` the value you want to be displayed should be in one of them depending on what you want.

Comment: @SidBarrack I'm sorry about that. I've edited my question now. Currently for the doses1, it has the value of 3. So what I wanted to do was something like this: (3/20)*100 so I could get the value of 15. And then pass that 15 in the correct doses1 array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by doing

```
   const realDoses = doses1.map((dose) => {
       return (dose / totalUsers) * 100;
   });
```

and setting the first dataset as:

```
       {
            label: "1st Dose",
            data: realDoses,
            backgroundColor: ["red"],

            borderWidth: 1
          },
```

It will show 15 instead of 3 now because I'm providing the chart with a new array that contains all the percentiles of the values in the first `doses1` array.

[image]

Try it out!